# Emberjs: Correct way binding of model / controller / view with fixture data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to get into ember to propose it to the CTO as the new technology to use for our refactor of the project.

I am tring to make an example of an already nested array of objects, but when I wanted to create a controller to give some behaviour, I lost acces to the model.

The example can be found in [this example](http://jsbin.com/pesuseyi/2/edit).

If I comment the "controler:" attribute from the view. All the data is show, but if you click in any top element, the click bubbles to the almost top controller.

I want to add a controller so that it can handle the click action, but it happens that when doing so every model attribute I print is not show. I've also tested with {{model.member}} but nothing.

I was wondering if in the template, the contentBinding="this" would really bind the model to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
<li>
  {{view App.InterestCategoryView contentBinding="this"}}
</li>
```

to:

```
<li>
  {{render interestCategory this}}
</li>
```

with this, 'render' will take of create a new 'interestCategory' controller for each item in the loop, as well as its view.

Comment: OMG. That just worked. Can't believe it was so "simple". Thankyou very much.

Comment: btw, remove this line "controller: App.InterestCategoryController.create()," from "App.InterestCategoryView", you don't need it.

Comment: Yes. I did before seeing your message. I thought that Ember fw should instance it by itself. Thanks again.